# Difference between 'I'm hungry' and 'I'm getting hungry'

Tags: verbs

Are they the same? Please give me an explanation! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not exactly the same, although they are quite close.

`I am hungry` would mean that you are currently in a state of hunger. You are hungry now.

`I'm getting hungry` would mean that you are starting to get feelings of hunger. You will be hungry soon. It would be a less severe way of expressing hunger than the first example.